# With WPF, how to retrieve the controls contained by a DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Basically I have a DataTemplate that contains Border, StackPanel and stuff, and later I use this DataTemplate as a ContentTemplate in many ContentControl(s).

These ContentControl(s) are named, but from the C# code I don't manage to find a way to get back my Border, StackPanel and stuff from them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do somthing like this:

```
// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);
```

And you can find more about it here: [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)

Comment: This helped me, but I had to change my ContentControl to a ContentPresenter otherwise it threw an error. There is detailed explanation on the ContentControl's issue here: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/28/how-to-use-findname-with-a-contentcontrol/

Answer (score 0):

Try `FindResource()`

[here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/07/26/679696.aspx)